# Fill a circle on a grid without builtin methods?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, fill

I want to fill a circle in an image with a color *without* using the built-in methods such as `drawOval()`. I've found algorithms to draw the border of a circle, but I can't figure out how to make a filled circle.

Comment: What tools do you want to use? Are you trying to do this by drawing one pixel at a time?

Comment: I suggest reading http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm.

Comment: You should first draw the border and then implement the `floodFill` algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: 1) I don't really know
2) That used the built-in fillOval() method.
3&4) I will look at this. Thanks.

Comment: @TriMill I think you are using numbering to refer to previous comments. Instead, you should post separate replies and notify who you are addressing with `@username`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you. I'm still trying to get used this. And I'm still trying not to end English sentences with semicolons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the links already given and then edit your question if you have more specific questions.

Comment: @thebjorn. That's massive overkill. If you have a method to figure out edge pixels, it's trivial to fill the circle in.

Comment: Please post some code showing how you drew the outline. You probably just need to change `==` to `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk through rows with coordinates from `center.Y - R` to `center.Y + R` and fill horizontal lines of needed length.

```
 for dy = - R to  R
    dx  = Math.Sqrt(R * R - dy * dy)    //semi-width
    drawline(center.X - dx, center.Y + dy, center.X + dx, center.Y + dy)
```

That's all.

(If you already use some circle-drawing algorithm like midpoint one or Bresenham one, you can substitute dx and dy with values from that algorithm)